# All New Contact Pages Blank?

Tags: contacts

On a new default CiviCRM installation on Wordpress, when trying to create any new contact (e.g. individual, household, etc), the screen is essentially empty.  For example, after performing a simplistic CiviCRM configuration and selecting Contacts>New Individual, I simply see a page titled "New Individual."  The page continues absolutely no fields, such as name, address, etc.  The same is true for all contact types.

Viewing the CiviCRM error log, I see no errors.  Enabling debugging produces no additional information either.  I have cleared the cache as well.  I can batch import individuals with no issue, but any page enabling manual contact creation is basically blank.

Thoughts?

Comment: Hi Greg. Welcome. So you can see contacts, but if you visit the equivalent of https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fadd&reset=1&ct=Individual (you can login to this site to do a comparison with yours) do you see nothing?

Comment: Correct.  I see nothing more than the title of "Add Individual" and the normal page footer.

Comment: have you tried some other themes? and if that doesn't help, can you try disabling other WP Plugins? something is interfering

Comment: and also check your basic WP + civi configuration.